# Duplicate div with general function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a cropping function applied on this div, i want to duplicate the div and make the function work for all divs, the original one and the duplicated divs, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the function", but `$('div').clone(true)` will let you clone the all `<div>` DOM elements along with any event handlers.